# margin issue of div tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the `div` tag with the class "Wrapper" have margin of some pixels from all side, especially from sidebar, but the margin is only increasing form the top and bottom why is it so?

2.When I using the hover styling for links only part of the whole tab is changing its color why is it so?

Please help.

Ps:- Im just a beginner Im sorry if my question is too vauge or silly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.head {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.head h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.head h4 {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.col {
  background-image: url(tony-webster-97532-unsplash.jpg);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.col h1 {
  padding-top: 160px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
}

.sidebar li {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 45px;
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.advert {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.advert h3 {
  padding-top: 265px;
  padding-bottom: 265px;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Happening.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="head">
    <h1>Happening.</h1>
    <h4>Your Name</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h1>College image in the backgroud</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h1>#Trending</h1>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 11</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="advert">
    <h3>This is the place for adverts</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hiring</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Collegues</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="feed">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="post">
        <img src="tony-webster-97532-unsplash.jpg" height="50" width="50">
        <h4>Placement Officer &#10004;</h4>
        <p>Some message from the authority</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Typing `margin: 40px 20px;` is shorthand for `margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom: 40px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right:20px;` If you want the same margin on every side, just type `margin: (x)px;`

Comment: to target all of the links inside the document use `a{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use padding Instead of margin. (for .wrapper .post)
2) add the property display: block (for a tag).

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.head {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.head h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.head h4 {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.col {
  background-image: url(tony-webster-97532-unsplash.jpg);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.col h1 {
  padding-top: 160px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
}

.sidebar li {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 45px;
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.advert {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.advert h3 {
  padding-top: 265px;
  padding-bottom: 265px;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* =====================================
 * this is my code
 * ====================================*/
.sidebar li{
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar li h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}
.sidebar li a{
    display: block;
}
.wrapper{
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.wrapper .post{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 40px 20px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Happening.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="head">
    <h1>Happening.</h1>
    <h4>Your Name</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h1>College image in the backgroud</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h1>#Trending</h1>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 11</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="advert">
    <h3>This is the place for adverts</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hiring</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Collegues</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="feed">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="post">
        <img src="tony-webster-97532-unsplash.jpg" height="50" width="50">
        <h4>Placement Officer &#10004;</h4>
        <p>Some message from the authority</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**first** `margin` can not set with `float` so that the reason I use `padding` instead `margin`.
**second**  you have to change `:hover` to `li` not the `a`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.head {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.head h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.head h4 {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.col {
  background-image: url(tony-webster-97532-unsplash.jpg);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.col h1 {
  padding-top: 160px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
}

.sidebar li {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 45px;
}

.sidebar li:hover{
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.advert {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.advert h3 {
  padding-top: 265px;
  padding-bottom: 265px;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Happening.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="head">
    <h1>Happening.</h1>
    <h4>Your Name</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h1>College image in the backgroud</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h1>#Trending</h1>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 11</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="advert">
    <h3>This is the place for adverts</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hiring</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Collegues</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="feed">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="post">
        <img src="tony-webster-97532-unsplash.jpg" height="50" width="50">
        <h4>Placement Officer &#10004;</h4>
        <p>Some message from the authority</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tell me if you need help

Comment: margin won't work correctly since the right and left element are floated!

Comment: check your answer

Comment: but the post is still not centered@לבנימלכה

Comment: but the post is still not centered in your edit@לבנימלכה

Comment: @TheWIseone set somthing else in `padding` (left/right/top/bottom) take a try

Answer (score 0):

First, it worked for me after adding `Float: left` in the `.wrapper` class

Second, you can try adding the below for your `CSS` file:

```
.sidebar li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the wrapper gets 40px for top and bottom, 20px for left and right.

Instead, you give like the below.

```
.wrapper {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**Note**: Change *margin-left* and *margin-right* according to your requirements.

To fix the sidebar buttons hover issues, make  as block element.

```
.sidebar ul li a {
  display: block;
}
```

Also Its not good to give *background-color* to `<li>` which wraps the `<a>`. Because, you cannot click on the entire area.

Comment: Thanks akash..!!:-)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve it,
this one will do:

**First Issue**

add `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` to your CSS you can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Then if your website is Static, add a fixed width to `.feed`, `.sidebar` and and .`advert`, if you want you could also use percentage instead of fixed width if your website is responsive (Work on any screen width).
also add `float: left` for `.feed` since the besides elements are floated.

**Second Issue**

Instead of `.sidebar li a:hover {background-color: grey;}` make it `.sidebar li:hover {background-color: grey;}`.

Check the edited snippet below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.head {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.head h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.head h4 {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.col {
  background-image: url(tony-webster-97532-unsplash.jpg);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.col h1 {
  padding-top: 160px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
width: 20%;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
}

.sidebar li {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 45px;
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.advert {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
width: 20%;
}

.advert h3 {
  padding-top: 265px;
  padding-bottom: 265px;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 30px;

}
.feed {
  width: 60%;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Happening.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="head">
    <h1>Happening.</h1>
    <h4>Your Name</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h1>College image in the backgroud</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h1>#Trending</h1>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending 11</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="advert">
    <h3>This is the place for adverts</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hiring</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Collegues</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="feed">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="post">
        <img src="tony-webster-97532-unsplash.jpg" height="50" width="50">
        <h4>Placement Officer &#10004;</h4>
        <p>Some message from the authority</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are most welcome dear :)
you could accept my answer if this solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

**First** I've added the fixed width 230px to sidebar and advert and I've added left and right margin of feed to 230px. Now wrapper will work properly. Please try

```
.feed{
  margin-left: 230px;
  margin-right: 230px;
}
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 230px;
}
.advert {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 230px;
}
```

**Second** you have to change :hover to li not the a

```
.sidebar li:hover {
background-color: grey;
}
```